# POJO to Map with Gson with custom deserializer

Tags: java, gson

I have a simple POJO class looking like this:

```
public class EventPOJO {

    public EventPOJO() {
    }

    public String id, title;
    // Looking for an annotation here
    public Timestamp startDate, endDate;
}
```

I have an instance of EventPOJO and need to deserialize this instance into a `Map<String, Object>` object.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
String json = gson.toJson(eventPOJO);
Map<String,Object> result = new Gson().fromJson(json, Map.class);
```

I need the `result` Map to contain the **key** `startDate` with the **value** of Type `Timestamp`.
(com.google.firebase.Timestamp)

Instead however `result` contains the **key** `startDate` with the **value** of Type `LinkedTreeMap` containing the nanoseconds and seconds.

I tried creating a **custom deserializer**:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Timestamp.class, new TimestampDeserializer());
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
String json = gson.toJson(eventPOJO);
Map<String,Object> result = gson.fromJson(json, Map.class);
```

**TimestampDeserializer.java**

```
public class TimestampDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Timestamp> {
    @Override
    public Timestamp deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        //not sure how to retrieve the seconds from the parameters
        return new Timestamp(999999999, 0);
    }
}
```

The deserialize never even gets called and I am still getting a Map with no Timestamp objects.

Comment: Please show how you set the fields of the type Timestamp: startDate, endDate. For instance, I initialized the POJO with manually created Timestamp and it showed the result fine: {id=123, startDate=Jan 13, 3920 8:07:07 AM}

Comment: @HoRn well my EventPOJO object is created from a database response (DocumentSnapshot):     `EventPOJO eventPOJO = documentSnapshot.toObject(EventPOJO.class);`   I checked in debugging mode: those fields are set and are actual Timestamp objects (com.google.firebase.Timestamp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a result as Map, then why not simply create a Map without using gson:

```
public class EventPOJO {

    public EventPOJO() {
    }

    public EventPOJO(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String id, title;
    // Looking for an annotation here
    public Timestamp startDate, endDate;

    public Map<String, Object> getMap() {
        Map<String, Object> res = new HashMap<>();
        res.put("id", id);
        res.put("title", title);
        res.put("startDate", startDate);
        res.put("endDate", endDate);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Then call

```
Map<String, Object> result = eventPOJO.getMap();
```